# Accessing Hash Keys with user inputted variables,Nil value No method error NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i had created a small ruby project which consists of JSON file. I stored the JSON data into hash keys. AND worte a method to access the data which is present in hash key using user input. But when i try to send use the user input i am getting this error

**`how_many_ingredients': undefined method`keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)**

I found this link with same question and tried that solution but still i'm getting the same error
[Accessing Hash Keys with user inputted variables, NoMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725957/accessing-hash-keys-with-user-inputted-variables-nomethoderror)

File one where all the methods are written

```
require 'json'

class Methods

  attr_accessor :name, :text
  def initilize(name)
    @name = name
    @text = text
  end



  def how_many_ingredients(text)
    puts 'text'

     file = File.read('a.json')
    hash = JSON.parse(file)
    #puts hash['recipes']['pizza'].keys 


    puts hash['recipes'][text].keys

  end

end
```

**File 2 where how_Many_ingredients method is accessed, I can see that the variable is passed to that method**

```
require './1'
class Hello < Methods


 person = Methods.new

person.test
puts "enter recipie"
person.name
str = gets
person.how_many_ingredients str
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you use `gets`, the input can contain newline and carriage return characters. You'll need to use `gets.chomp` to filter these. This is likely the cause of the issue in your program.

Compare the following two:

```
> puts gets.size
"Hello!"
# 7

> puts gets.chomp.size
"Hello!"
# 6
```

Note that you'll still need to extend your program to account for user inputted keys that are not in your hash.

Comment: Awesome!! Drenmi , thanks alot .... bit new to ruby and now im trying to understand whats going

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that there will always be a hash stored at `hash['recipes'][text]` - you need to cater to the cases where it isn't.

A simple way to do this is to work your way down through the hash with `&&` symbols - if any step is nil (or false), the line will return nil (or false) rather than exploding.  eg

```
puts hash['recipes'] && hash['recipes'][text].is_a?(Hash) && hash['recipes'][text].keys
```

Note i'm testing that `hash['recipes'][text]` is a hash (rather than just a string for example) before calling `.keys` on it.